# Accessing Property that has a setter inside a template

Tags: wpf

I have a canvas who takes many type of object and shows them in specific locations.
Most of the objects has a Location property which is set by a “Setter” and it works great.

I have one complex object – assembled from 4 bitmaps.
I want to be able to set each bitmap location using the canvas.top and canvas.left but not with the location in the setter (they don’t have it) but using their own location property.

Here is the code.

My problem is that WPF completely ignores my canvas.top and canvas.left assignment, even if I use numbers and not binding – nothing happens as well.

What might be the problem ?

Here is my current code. 
The ComplexBitmap draws itself in 0,0 and not where expected.

```
<ItemsControl Name="itemtest"  ItemsSource="{Binding}" Height="576" Background="#FFB0B4B4" Width="704">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <local2:DragCanvas x:Name="canvas1" AllowDragging="true" AllowDragOutOfView="False"  Width="704" Height="576" Background="#3AC2DED4"/>
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
                            <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding Path=Location.X, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                            <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Path=Location.Y,  Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                            <Setter Property ="Visibility" Value="{Binding Path= ShowOnDemo, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" />
                        </Style>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplateSelector>
                        <local:CustomTemplateSelector>
                            .
                            <local:CustomTemplateSelector.BitmapTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <StackPanel>
                                        <Image Source="{Binding Path=Bitmaps/myBitmap}" Canvas.Left="{Binding Path=Location.X, Mode=TwoWay}" Canvas.Top="{Binding Path=Location.Y, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                                    </StackPanel>
                               </DataTemplate>
                                </local:CustomTemplateSelector.BitmapTemplate>
                            .
                            <local:CustomTemplateSelector.ComplexBitmapTemplate >
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Grid>
                                        <StackPanel>
                                            <Image Source="{Binding Path=TopLeftBitmapObj.myBitmap}" Canvas.Left="400" Canvas.Top="400" /> <-- Here I've tried to bind to another property, but even the 400 didn't work --> 
                                       </StackPanel>
                                       <-- Here comes 3 more bitmaps --> 
                                    </Grid>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </local:CustomTemplateSelector.ComplexBitmapTemplate>
                        </local:CustomTemplateSelector>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplateSelector>
                </ItemsControl>
```

Comment: Sounds  like your items might not be placed immediately on the canvas? can you post a screenshot of the Visual Tree taken from Snoop?

Comment: Double check your Source Binding Path also.

Comment: @raptor - source is ok as the images does shows, but on 0,0 and not 400,400....

Comment: +1 for HighCore, seems like `Image` is not immediate child for canvas. Have you tried using Canvas binding with `StackPanel` and `Datagrid`

Answer (score 0):

Please check the following:

1. Run in visual studio in debug mode and check for path error (As  Raptor sugested)
2. Remove
       the Style from the content presenter (As you said, ComplexBitmap
       does not contains       Location property...)